# Questionário dinâmico php SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá,
 estou construindo uma ferramenta de calibração (dado um checklist o usuário precisa selecionar os campos que estão de acordo (ou não) com uma ligação ou roteiro.

> ```
> Ex.:
> 1)Colaborador inicia o atendimento conforme diretrizes.
> a) conforme
> b) não conforme
> c) não se aplica.
> ```

A principio a ferramenta vai permitir selecionar o tipo de campo ( radio,checkbox,select e text).
Atualmente ja tenho boa parte pronta, a questão é: qual a melhor forma de estruturar o meu banco? Como devo relacionar as respostas e as perguntas? atualmente minhas tabelas estao assim:

Tabela Formulário

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[formulario](
    [id] [varchar](13) NULL,
    [nome] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [descricao] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [pergunta] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [resposta] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [tipo] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [iPergunta] [int] NULL,//indice da pergunta
    [iResposta] [int] NULL,//indice da resposta
    [qtdPerguntas] [int] NULL,//total de perguntas
    [qtdRespostas] [int] NULL,
    [responsavel] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [criacao] [datetime] NULL,
    [atualizacao] [datetime] NULL
)
```

Tabela Resposta:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[resposta](
    [formulario] [varchar](13) NULL,
    [pergunta] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [resposta] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [respondente] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [data] [datetime] NULL
)
```

Eu preciso de uma outra tabela para que o *adm* possa falar quais são as respostas corretas, mas essa estrutura não parece adequada.

Comment: Para que serve  os campos `iPergunta` e `iResposta`? Pelo qe da para entender eles servem para dizer qual a pergunta e respota do formulário. É importante entender isso para que a comunidade possa dar uma resposta mais adequada para você.

Comment: Bom Thiago, eles são o indice da pergunta e da resposta, meio que um contador.

Comment: Pelo que entendi o `iPergunta` iria receber o id da pergunta do formulário. Mas se o formulário tiver várias perguntas, pela modelagem que mostrou, acredito que isso não iria funcionar.

Comment: Não, o iPergunta é o índice. veja bem, suponha que eu inseri 2 perguntas, a primeira com 3 respostas e a segunda com duas,a estrutura seria: 
Pergunta 1: iPergunta 0
Resposta a iResposta 0
Resposta b iResposta 1
Resposta c iResposta 2
Pergunta 2 iPergunta 2
Resposta a iResposta 3
Resposta b iResposta 4

Answer (score 2):

Eu criaria o modelo mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

**Formulário**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[formulario](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL, // chave primaria
    [nome] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [descricao] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [tipo] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [responsavel] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [criacao] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [atualizacao] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

**Resposta**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[resposta](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL, // chave primaria
    [id_formulario] [int] NOT NULL, // chave extrangeira
    [id_pergunta] [int] NOT NULL, // chave extrangeira
    [id_opcao] [int] NOT NULL // chave extrangeira
)
```

**Pergunta**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pergunta](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL, // chave primaria
    [pergunta] [varchar](150) NOT NULL
)
```

**Opção**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[opcao](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL, // chave primaria
    [id_pergunta] [int] NOT NULL, // chave extrangeira
    [opcao] [varchar](150) NOT NULL
)
```

Fazendo desta forma, você poderia criar uma pergunta com quantas opções de resposta você quisesse. E depois na tabela `Resposta`, você pode relacionar várias perguntas a um formulário, e registrar a opção marcada pelo usuário.

Comment: Assim fica bem melhor, preciso pensar em uma forma de fazer isso no backend, pois para o meu adm que vai inserir o banco, vai fazer a inserção como se fosse o modelo de criação de formulário do google forms. Imagino que com essa estrutura, se fosse criado cada item de forma separada, seria muito mais trabalhoso.

Comment: Você pode colocar os itens junto as perguntas, mas terá uma quantidade fixa de itens e se você quiser uma quantidade de itens variadas de acordo com a pergunta, terá campos nulos. Da forma que fiz a modelagem, isso não iria acontecer.